# Query without partition by or functions like rank()

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

Suppose we have the table students (name, grade, group, year)
We want a query that ranks for each group the corresponding students.
I know that this can be done easy with rank() OVER ( partition by group order by grade DESC ). But I think that this can also be done with a self join or a subquery. Any ideas?

Comment: It is much more efficient with `rank()`.  Why would you want to do it any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `rank()` is:

```
select s.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from students s2
        where s2.group = s.group and
              s2.grade > s.grade
       ) as rank
from students s;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in the equivalent of partition by. How could we implement the partition by, without the OVER ( partition by ) ?

Comment: @valer . . . (1) This answers your question.  (2) If you look at the correlation clause, I think it is pretty obvious what the equivalent to the `partition by` is.

Comment: just to be sure, is the partition by equivalent to this continuing from your query ( from student s order by group, grade DESC ) ?

Comment: @valer . . . `partition by group` --> `s2.group = s.group`.